# Deleting a file from computer, but keep it on sync'd external HDD

Tags: sync, synctoy

after synchronizing, I'd like to delete some files from my computer, but KEEP them in my external hard disc (I'm using 'Synctoy'.) what do I have to do in that case?

In other words- How do I keep files in my external hard disc after deleting them from my computer?

Comment: If I remember SyncToy correctly, there are three modes for each folder pair. "sync", "echo" and something else (can't remember the name of it). Sync is bidirection and mirrors deletes, the other two are one-directional, and one of them *doesn't* mirror deletes - you want to find and see if that one meets your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You should use "Contribute" (left folder is the one on your computer, right folder is the one on the external disk).

> New and updated files are copied left to right. Renames on the left are repeated on the right. No deletions.

The screenshot is from SyncToy 2.1

[image: Synctoy screenshot]

Comment: Ah ha! *Contribute*, that's the one! Have a +1 for filling in the gaps of my comment for me.